# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on Ajax Request

Tags: json, ajax, rest, jwt

This is a bit of a noob question and I'm new to API requests and AJAX so bear with me.

This request has a JWT token (which i'm doubly unfamiliar with), and I was able to get the request to work with Postman by putting in the headers:

**Key**: Authorization

**Value**: JWT eytJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIW6GHIH8g(not my real key)

This returns some JSON results which is great.

However, when I go to test the request with AJAX, code here:

```
$( "#test-fill" ).on( "click", function() {

    console.log('Begin test:');

    var api_url = 'https://builder.guidebook.com/open-api/v1/schedule-tracks/'
    var key = 'eytJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIW6GHIH8g' // not real for stackoverflow question


    $.ajax({
        url: api_url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'JWT ' + key,
        },      
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
            alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
        },
    })

});
```

I get the error message :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://builder.guidebook.com/open-api/v1/schedule-tracks/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://builder.guidebook.com/open-api/v1/schedule-tracks/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Why is this happening and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' response header returned from your server on every request. The value of this server response header is either your client URL, or "*", saying "allow all".

Here is some general detail:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

How you set this is completely dependent on the server the backend is running (at https://builder.guidebook.com in this case).

**Why does Postman work, but not the browser?**

Postman doesn't worry about CORS by default, so it won't react to a missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' response header, but browsers are CORS compliant, so they will block requests based on this.

**Alternatives and Workarounds:**

1. If your client that's doing the AJAX was on the same server (within https://builder.guidebook.com), this would not be a problem.
2. If you have no access to add CORS response headers to the source server, you can spin up your own server (e.g. locally) to proxy requests. Similar to Postman, web servers don't by default worry about CORS for outgoing requests to other servers.

**Note:** This is a common problem with local client UI development that needs to integrate with remote servers. Development approaches like webpack offer automatic proxying for exactly this kind of common situation.